# Can anyone tell me why media query is registering at breakpoint before and not the one im targeting

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
      .priority-images{
      width: 65% !important;
    }
    }   
 @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
      .priority-images{
      width: 90% !important;
    }
    }
```

.priority-images is registering 620 breakpoint instead of 320 breakpoint and its frustrating me, I know it targets everything below but when I have used this method with success before any suggestions?

Comment: I have provided a reason what is happening right here. If you could tell me what you want to achieve, i would like to help :)

Comment: still not working

Comment: Dear Daniel, I have mentioned exactly what is going on with the media queries that you have written. Your statement "priority-images is registering 620 breakpoint instead of 320 breakpoint and its frustrating me" is not correct itself my friend. Because, 320px is what is being applied in your case. That's why I would like to know what you exactly u want as an output. Just provide an image or place your HTML in the question as well, for me to understand what u want to achieve in this case. U may put your code in jsfiddle and share link with me. I will try to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you are following both `mobile-first (min-width)` and `desktop-first(max-width)` approach together. And there is an overlap from `320px to 620px` here, in which case `320px takes precendence not the 620px.`

In your media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {...}
```

The viewport is targeted from `width=0` to `width=620px` of the screen. However when you used:

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {...}
```

Now when your browser width gets 320px of width, the 620px media query is overridden by this one.

And as per my observation and code snipper, **the *.priority-images* is not getting precedence at *620px* but at *320px* itself .** The `min-width:320px` media query takes full control of CSS as soon as the Browser width gets greater than or equal to 320px. So, I don't see `min-width:620px` media query being applied after the *320px* browser width at all.

Check the below code snippet:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
.priority-images {
  height: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
  .priority-images {
    width: 65% important;
    background: orange;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .priority-images {
    width: 90% important;
    background: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <article class="priority-images">
      There are no accidents ... No there are not !!!
    </article>
  </body>

  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the 320 breakpoint to be applied when 320 screen size is reached change the

```
 max-width: 620px
 min-width: 320px
```

to

```
min-width: 620px     
max-width: 320px
```

here is the codepen
https://codepen.io/shammlo/pen/YzGQKjQ